# Magento 2 default checkout page too slow

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment, slow-response

3 with default checkout but it loading too slow
in that too

```
rest/default/V1/guest-carts/W4tUoafhV2AvU8CeJcnlzuALWRqSzfE1/shipping-information and payment-information
```

these api call taking time i disabled used payment methods and shipping
implemented cdn
Fallowed https://onilab.com/blog/magento-checkout-slow-fix-it-in-8-simple-steps/
https://bsscommerce.com/blog/magento-2-checkout-slow/

Select one of the payment methods then
Click on place order

payment information taking time
/rest/default/V1/carts/mine/payment-information

i checked this link
https://digitalstartup.co.uk/t/why-is-the-place-order-action-slow/1040/10
but no luck
can any one tell how we can solve